# EXC Bad Instruction

Tags: swift

In was wondering why I keep getting this error message, EXC Bad Instruction could someone help me out and tell me why.

Here is the code.

```
 func updateStocks() {
    let stockManager:StockManagerSingleton = StockManagerSingleton.sharedInstance
    stockManager.updateListOfSymbols(stocks)

    //Repeat this method after 15 secs. (For simplicity of the tutorial we are not cancelling it never)
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(15 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        {
            self.updateStocks()
        }
    )
}

//4
func stocksUpdated(notification: NSNotification) {
    let values = (notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,NSArray>)
    let stocksReceived:NSArray = values[kNotificationStocksUpdated]!
    stocks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for quote in stocksReceived {
        let quoteDict:NSDictionary = quote as! NSDictionary
        let changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as! String
        let changeInPercentStringClean: NSString = (changeInPercentString as NSString).substringToIndex((changeInPercentString as NSString).length-1)
        stocks.append(quoteDict["symbol"] as! String,changeInPercentStringClean.doubleValue)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Symbols Values updated :)")
}
}
```

The line with the error in it is,

```
let changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as! String
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error message? Also, try printing `quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"]` to the console

Comment: Yes, I will put the full error. @ Jojodmo

Answer (score 1):

The error states that Swift attempted to unwrap a `nil` value, as you stated on this line

```
let changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as! String
```

Swift attempts to force setting the value of `quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"]` to a `String`, because you use `as!`, instead, you should use `as?`, which will set the value to `nil` if the value cannot be found

```
let changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as? String
```

You could set this to a default value by using the `??` operator. For example, if you wanted the default value to be `0.0%`, you could use

```
let changeInPercentString = (quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as? String) ?? "0.0%"
```

The inherent problem is most likely either that `quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"]` does not exist, or `quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"]` is not a String - it may be an NSString or simply a Double value.

If you find out that it is supposed to be an NSString, for example, you will need to change how you cast the value

```
let changeInPercentString: NSString = (quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as? NSString) ?? "0.0%"
```